# Firebase Cloud Messaging server key not displaying at Console

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

My server key is not displaying at my firebase Console. What configuration should I do?

[image: Here Is the Console]

Comment: That is strange. Have you tried accessing it via different browsers?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue and is being addressed. Usually you would get into this state when the API key automatically generated by the creation of the Firebase project is deleted from the Google Developer console. The Firebase console UI currently only shows the automatically generated server API key, and nothing if that key is deleted.

You can still use any valid server API key in the corresponding Google Developer project. So go to the Google Developer console and use one of the Server API keys there or create one if it does not exist.

Comment: +1 I see. Interesting. If the auto-generated Server API Key is deleted, it will not display anything, but if I generated one from the Google Console, will the Firebase Console automatically show that one?

Comment: Not at this time, but it will still be a valid key to use to send FCM messages.